# Hooking winapi function show me dllimport error

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

i am trying to write a article about `api hooking` and `WinApi` functions. Like the core function of each and every Windows graphical interfaces is `SendMessage` i was trying to use `minhook` to capture these messages and show it in my graphical interface. I did api hooking of a easy function to understand more about minhook in the follow way:

```
#include "C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\minhook\Dynamic\MinHook_133_src\include\MinHook.h"//MHook header
#include <iostream>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#include <conio.h>//For getch
using namespace std;

typedef void (*WRITEFOOBAR)();//Typedef for the hooked function
static WRITEFOOBAR Basewritefoobar;//Backup of the originak fonction

void Writefoobar();//Original function
void Hookedwritefoobar();//Original function's redirection

static bool Hook();

template <typename T>
inline MH_STATUS MH_CreateHookEx(void* target, void* const base, T** original)
{
    return MH_CreateHook(target, base, reinterpret_cast<void**>(original));
}

int main()
{
    if (!Hook())//Hook "Writefoobar"
    {
        cout << "Hook failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Writefoobar();//Standard call to Writefoobar, but instead, Hookedwritefoobar will be executed

    cout << "Press a key to exit" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

bool Hook()
{
    if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (MH_CreateHookEx((void*)&Writefoobar, (void*)&Hookedwritefoobar, &Basewritefoobar) != MH_OK)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return MH_EnableHook((void*)&Writefoobar) == MH_OK;
}

void Writefoobar()
{
    cout << "foobar" << endl;
}

void Hookedwritefoobar()
{
    cout << "BLUESCREEN Software" << endl;
}
```

This is example works so fine. But now i was trying to capture `SendMessage` Winapi Function. So i tried to make a similar example at my working example. The example is the follow:

```
#include "C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\minhook\Dynamic\MinHook_133_src\include\MinHook.h"//MHook header
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#include <conio.h>//For getch
using namespace std;

typedef void (*SENDMESSAGEW)();//Typedef for the hooked function
static SENDMESSAGEW Basewritefoobar;//Backup of the originak fonction

LRESULT WINAPI SendMessageW(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

static const wchar_t *hiddenprocess=L"tusitio";

LRESULT WINAPI BSSSendMessageW(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if ( msg == LVM_INSERTITEMW || msg == LVM_SETITEMW)//Intercepts LVM_INSERTITEM and LVM_SETITEM messages
    {
        if (!lstrcmpW(((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText, hiddenprocess))//The lparam is a LVITEM* struct.
        {
            return 0;//If the item name is the same as process we want to hide, we simply return 0 (and we do not call the real SendMessage function.
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return SendMessage(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);//Calls the real SendMessage function.
}

static bool Hook();

template <typename T>
inline MH_STATUS MH_CreateHookEx(void* target, void* const base, T** original)
{
    return MH_CreateHook(target, base, reinterpret_cast<void**>(original));
}

int main()
{
    if (!Hook())//Hook "Writefoobar"
    {
        cout << "Hook failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Press a key to exit" << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

bool Hook()
{
    if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (MH_CreateHookEx((void*)&SendMessageW, (void*)&BSSSendMessageW, &Basewritefoobar) != MH_OK)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return MH_EnableHook((void*)&SendMessageW) == MH_OK;
}
```

However not seems to be compiled fine. I get the follow error's:

```
$ gcc -o dllmain.o -c Dynamic.cpp                                               Dynamic.cpp:11:16: warning: 'LRESULT SendMessageW(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 LRESULT WINAPI SendMessageW(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
                ^~~~~~~~
```

My dll trying to hooking sendmessage:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\minhook\Dynamic\MinHook_133_src\include\MinHook.h"//MHook header
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*SENDMESSAGEW)();//Typedef for the hooked function
static SENDMESSAGEW Basewritefoobar;//Backup of the originak fonction

LRESULT WINAPI SendMessageW(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

static const wchar_t *hiddenprocess=L"tusitio";

LRESULT WINAPI BSSSendMessageW(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if ( msg == LVM_INSERTITEMW || msg == LVM_SETITEMW)//Intercepts LVM_INSERTITEM and LVM_SETITEM messages
    {
        if (!lstrcmpW(((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText, hiddenprocess))//The lparam is a LVITEM* struct.
        {
            return 0;//If the item name is the same as process we want to hide, we simply return 0 (and we do not call the real SendMessage function.
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return SendMessage(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);//Calls the real SendMessage function.
}

static bool Hook();

template <typename T>
inline MH_STATUS MH_CreateHookEx(void* target, void* const base, T** original)
{
    return MH_CreateHook(target, base, reinterpret_cast<void**>(original));
}


extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) void __cdecl SendWrite()
{ 
    //SendWrite Call

}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst, ULONG ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    //Different behaviors depending on the reason why DllMain is called
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            if (!Hook())//Hook "Writefoobar"
            {
                cout << "Hook failed" << endl;
                return 1;
            }
            //SendMessageW(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

bool Hook()
{
    if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (MH_CreateHookEx((void*)&SendMessageW, (void*)&BSSSendMessageW, &Basewritefoobar) != MH_OK)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return MH_EnableHook((void*)&SendMessageW) == MH_OK;
}
```

At the moment when i compile my dll not seems to compile fine:

```
$ gcc -o dllmain.o -c dllmain.cpp
dllmain.cpp:14:16: warning: 'LRESULT SendMessageW(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 LRESULT WINAPI SendMessageW(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

In general i'm trying to make a minimal example of this dll hooking `sendmessage` winapi function.
Why i am trying to do this? For researching, and i get the data since there:

[Hooking SendMessage](https://bluecode.fr/apihookingandprocesshiding.html)

Comment: you give to compiler two different declaration of `SendMessageW` as result of course error - are this not absolute clear for you ?

Comment: What does any of this have to do with API hooking?

Comment: First, is related with api hooking because like i say in the post i am hooking sendmessage winapi function... And second, i updated the post because i included unnecesary errors and my title was not very descriptive, fault mine.. Sorry for incoveniences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
LRESULT WINAPI SendMessageW(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

This function has already been declared by `#include <windows.h>` but with a slightly different declaration related to how the function is imported from a .DLL.

Just remove your declaration and the error should go away...